# Update Object with unique values from Child object using Aggregate result

Tags: apex, map, aggregate, bulkification

I am trying to update a field on the Quote (Operational_Start_Date__c) from the results of an aggregate result query.
The trigger runs on quote, queries QuoteLine for unique values and update the Quote with the unique values. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working;

```
trigger SB_QuoteAdditionalUpdates on SBQQ__Quote__c (before insert, before update) {


        Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();

         for (SBQQ__Quote__c quotes : Trigger.new) {

                quoteIds.add(quotes.id);

         }

            List<AggregateResult> uniqueCountries = ([SELECT  Country_Operational_Date__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c IN:quoteIds 
                                                        AND country_code__c <> null AND Employee_CountFormula__c <> null GROUP BY Country_Operational_Date__c]);


            if(uniqueCountries.Size()>0 ){


                for (AggregateResult uniqueCountry : uniqueCountries){

                    quotes.Operational_Start_Date__c = String.valueOf(uniqueCountry.get('Country_Operational_Date__c'));
                    system.debug('======>'+String.valueOf(uniqueCountry.get('Country_Operational_Date__c')));

                }               
            }

}
```

When I make the for loop run through the aggregate result (not optimized/bulkified), it updates the quote but it's only updating with one of the unique values and the quote might have had 3 unique values.

Comment: [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) can do what you want out of the box.

Comment: Is it still on Appexchange? Tried installing one from an unlisted link and got this error, 

AppExchange Package is Deprecated

The AppExchange package has been deprecated and can no longer be installed. Please try installing a newer version, or contact the package owner directly to resolve.

Comment: Never mind. Found the latest one. Thanks!! Here is the lastest one, https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries#packaged-release-history